# Relationship between eigen values of matrix A and A+3I

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the relationship between the eigen values of a matrix A and those of the matrix A+3I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A(x)=cx, (A+3I)(x)=A(x)+3x=(c+3)(x), (A+3I)(x)=d(x), A(x)=(d-3)(x)$

So $c$ eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $c+3$ eigenvalue of $A+3I$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $B=A+3I$. Consider Jordan normal form $J=SAS^{-1}$ and compute $SBS^{-1}$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are on the diagonal of $J$. So the eigenvalues of $B$ are those of $A$ plus $3$.